# Symfony Doctrine createQueryBuilder From() alias not working

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

when trying to execute this query it is complaining:

> [2/2] QueryException: [Semantical Error] line 0, col 443 near 'User
>   user LEFT': Error: Class 'User' is not defined.

I really don't even know why I need the alias in my from but I added it there and its not working.

The Entity class name is "User"

```
    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from('User','user')
        ->select('user.email,
                person.givenName,
                person.familyName,
                contactPoint.contactInfo,
                organization.legalName,
                postalAddress.streetAddress1,
                postalAddress.streetAddress2,
                postalAddress.city,
                postalAddress.postalCode,
                country.name,
                region.name')

        ->leftJoin('person', 'WITH', "user.person_id=person.id")
        ->leftJoin('contactPoint', 'WITH', "person.contactPoint_id=contactPoint.id")
        ->leftJoin('organization', 'WITH', "person.organization_id=organization.id")
        ->leftJoin('postalAddress', 'WITH', "organization.postal_address_id=postalAddress.id")
        ->leftJoin('country', 'WITH', "postalAddress.country_id=country.id")
        ->leftJoin('region', 'WITH', "postalAddress.region_id=region.id")
        ->where("user.email = '$email' ")
        ->getQuery();
    dump($query->getArrayResult());die();
```

UPDATED WORKING QUERY ////////////////////

```
$user = $this->get('security.token_storage')->getToken()->getUser();

    $email = $user->getEmail();

    $query = $em->createQueryBuilder()
        ->from(User::class,'user')
        ->select('user.email,
                person.givenName,
                person.familyName,
                contactPoint.contactInfo,
                organization.legalName,
                postalAddress.streetAddress1,
                postalAddress.streetAddress2,
                postalAddress.city,
                postalAddress.postalCode,
                country.name,
                region.name')

        ->leftJoin(Person::class, 'person', 'WITH', "user.accountOwner=person.id")
        ->leftJoin(ContactPoint::class, 'contactPoint', 'WITH', "person.contactPoint=contactPoint.id")
        ->leftJoin(Organization::class, 'organization', 'WITH', "person.organization=organization.id")
        ->leftJoin(PostalAddress::class, 'postalAddress', 'WITH', "organization.postalAddress=postalAddress.id")
        ->leftJoin(Country::class, 'country', 'WITH', "postalAddress.country=country.id")
        ->leftJoin(Region::class, 'region', 'WITH', "postalAddress.region=region.id")
        ->where("user.email = '$email' ")
        ->getQuery();
    dump($query->getResult());die();
```

Comment: here is the revised working query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the fully qualified class name, try with:

```
    ->from(User::class,'user')
```

instead of

```
    ->from('User','user')
```

More general, referring to the [documentation](http://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-for-objects-with-dql) of Symfony Doctrine:

> you need to think in terms of selecting PHP objects, instead of rows
>   in a database. For this reason, you select from the
>   `AppBundle:Product` entity (an optional shortcut for the
>   `AppBundle\Entity\Product` class) and then alias it as `p`.

So you should use the field of the class instead of the column name of the table in the DQL statement.

Hope this help

Comment: thanks that did help did not see that example in any of the documentation, now its complaining about my peron in the joins shuold that be the class name or actual table name? [Semantical Error] line 0, col 484 near 'Person WITH LEFT': Error: Class 'Person' is not defined.

Comment: looks like I need to change all my joins to ClassName::class, 'alias'

Comment: now working also had to change the id columns of my joins to the class property names

Comment: hi @user1930591 I update my answer with a reference to the doc about the use of the field of the object instead of the column of the table.

Comment: Hi @user1930591 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: one more thing I need is it possible to get a country object instead of an ID with this query?

Comment: Befoer I was using $form->setData('country' => $postalAddress->getCountry) which returned an object and set my country list when I try to use setData() now with a name or ID it is not setting it